# is this SOAP request valid?

Tags: soap, glassfish-4

a soap client (Control-M) produces the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:CTMOP="http://example.com/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <CTMOP:importFile xmlns="http://example.com/">
            <arg0>abc.pdf</arg0>
            <arg1>def.pdf</arg1>
        </CTMOP:importFile>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Glassfish 4 is not possible to process this request.

`Received WS-I BP non-conformant Unquoted SoapAction HTTP header`

If the `xmlns="http://example.com/` is removed from the importFile operation the method
is processed by Glassfish 4. so this works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:CTMOP="http://example.com/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <CTMOP:importFile>
            <arg0>abc.pdf</arg0>
            <arg1>def.pdf</arg1>
        </CTMOP:importFile>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Is it a Glassfish 4 bug or is the SOAP request invalid?